# jquery get().reverse() in vanilla js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to translate my jquery code into vanilla js.
this piece of code:

```
let count = 1;
        $($(".card").get().reverse()).each(function () {
            $(this).addClass("zIndex" + count);
            count++;
        });
```

basically i have a bunch of divs with class `.card`, for each of these i need to assign the class `zIndex` with a decreasing number, so that it comes out like this:

```
<div class="card zIndex3"></div>
<div class="card zIndex2"></div>
<div class="card zIndex1"></div>
```

I'm going to be honest, i have no clue where to start, especially regarding the `$($(".card").get().reverse())`

any help or even clues on how to proceed is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [document.getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

and 

[Array.prototype.reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)

are your friends. Is the logic something need help with or just syntax?

Comment: No need for .reverse, just count backward: `var count = length` .. `count--`

Comment: @k8xian both :) that would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

you can use the array.reverse method in js https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse

and to translate the jquery loop you have, you can :

- create an array with `document.querySelectorAll` and `[...data]` syntax
- directly call reverse on this array

`[...document.querySelectorAll('.card')].reverse()`

```js
// in jquery
let count = 1;
$($(".card").get().reverse()).each(function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
});

console.log('*******************');
 
 // without jquery
 count = 1;
[...document.querySelectorAll('.card')].reverse().forEach(elem => {
  console.log(elem.innerText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card zIndex3">1</div>
<div class="card zIndex2">2</div>
<div class="card zIndex1">3</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One alternative to `get()` method in jquery is `querySelectorAll` with javascript.

```
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
```

And equalized to `reverse` is creating a decreasing loop start from last index of the cards and end with index equal to zero.

```
for (let i = cards.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   const card = cards[i];
   cards.style.zIndex = i;
}
```